# I want to wipe a new laptop of Windows10 and install Ubuntu from an iso on a flash drive

Tags: system-installation

Long story short, bought the gf a cheap new laptop for Christmas, and it only has a 32gb drive. Buying a larger drive is not an option at this time. Turns out Windoze 10 eats up 17gb out of the box, and it is now at 29gb with more updates needed.

I have the Ubuntu iso on a flash drive. Laptop does not have a cd tray. i want to completely wipe the drive and start over with Ubuntu. Is this possible, and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it's is possible.

Follow instructions here to create the USB disk http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

And here to install: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

I'm glad you chose Linux. Your gf will appreciate it, I hope.